# Looking for an open source C/C++ image / video thumbnail generation libraries

Tags: c++, c, image-processing, thumbnails

I am looking for an open source C/C++ image/video thumbnail generation libraries.

(other than ffmpeg or DevIL)

Answer (score 3):

Will [Image Magick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) work? It is quite a capable library with C++ (and C) bindings. It does support grabbing still frames from some video formats, see [here](http://rich.milns.com/2009/08/imagemagick-exporting-a-still-frame/). It's a command-line example, but should work from the API as well.

Comment: Image Magick is fine, but it does not support video thumbnail generation AFAIK.

Comment: What format are your videos in? ImageMagick does support some AVI formats.

Answer (score 1):

Try [**ffmpegthumbnailer**](https://code.google.com/p/ffmpegthumbnailer/downloads/list):

> This thumbnailer was designed to be as fast and lightweight as possible. The only dependencies are ffmpeg, libpng and libjpeg.